# Redirect the query output to a text file with sqlite on windows?

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm doing some queries using Sqlite in Windows (I execute it as `sqlite3 mydb.db`) but I can't redirect the output (I'm trying to do as a normal command line way like `.tables` > `new_db_output.txt`) because sqlite runs as an a program under the command line.

In the [official sqlite web page](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html) is a section called **Writting results to a file** but doesn't work in the way I try:

`.tables .output new_db_output.txt`

neither

`.tables | .output new_db_output.txt`

Any idea to get the output to a file?

**Note:** I'm using sqlite3 & windows 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dot commands of the `sqlite3` command-line shell cannot be combined.

`.output` affects all following commands; just execute it beforehand:

```
.output new_db_output.txt
.tables
.output
```

Comment: Thanks, by using .output redirects all the subsequent queries to a file and is just what I need. :)

Comment: If you only want the next command to go to a file, you can use the `.once` command followed by a filename. Then you won't have to follow up with another `.output` command to resume output to stdout.

Answer (score 6):

### From outside the SQLite command line interface

If you are working from outside the command line interface of SQLite:

- directly in the system terminal (bash, PowerShell),
- or running from some script

you could use the conventional system redirection and pipes mechanisms.

```sh
sqlite3 database "SELECT * FROM table;" >  somefile
sqlite3 database "SELECT * FROM table;" >> somefile
sqlite3 database "SELECT * FROM table;" | tee somefile
```

- The first example creates a new file with the SQLite output.
- The second example append the output to the file (if it exists).
- In the last example, `tee` copies the standard output to `somefile` (like the `>` redirection).
  However, you will see the output in the terminal.
  Note that `tee` is a Unix/Linux utility.

### An extra

You can produce a CSV file using the command `.mode`.

```sh
sqlite3 database ".mode csv" "SELECT * FROM table;" > somefile.csv
```

Or with headers (thank @Mike Kelly)

```sh
sqlite3 database ".mode csv" ".headers on" "SELECT * FROM table;" > somefile.csv
```

Comment: Thanks.. Another option to get a header for your CSV output:


sqlite3 db.sqlite ".mode csv" ".headers on" "select * from ...;" > somefile.csv