# Error trying to access firefox cookies using python

Tags: python, firefox, cookies

Hi I am working on using firefox cookies in python. I referred [this](http://krosinski.blogspot.in/2012/07/make-websites-recognise-pythonurllias.html). I am getting "DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database" error. I have gone through other answers too and they seem to suggest compatibility issue but none of them details how to do away the issue.

OS: windows 7, Firefox version: 38, Python: 2.7.9.

Please help me fix this issue. 
Below is the code. BTW I have copy of 'cookies.sqlite' in my working directory, so don't bother answering my path is incorrect.

Thanks.

```
import urllib2
import cookielib
from sqlite3 import dbapi2

host = 'www.reddit.com'
ff_cookie_file= 'cookies.sqlite'

file = open("cookie.txt", "w")
file.write("#LWP-Cookies-2.0\n")
match = '%%%s%%' % host
con = dbapi2.connect(ff_cookie_file)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select name, value, path, host from moz_cookies where host like ?", [match])
for item in cur.fetchall():
    cookie = "Set-Cookie3: %s=\"%s\"; path=\"%s\";  \
    domain=\"%s\"; expires=\"2038-01-01 00:00:00Z\"; version=0\n" % (item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3])
file.write(cookie)
file.close()

cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
cj.load("cookie.txt")

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
```

Edit: running the command "sqlite3 cookies.sqlite" gives the following output:

```
python: can't open file 'sqlite3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I guess reason for this is that my system has no file as "sqlite3.exe".

For further confirmation about whether or not my sqlite3 works, I created the db, inserted few values and queried it. It worked like charm. [here is the link](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/18/python-a-simple-step-by-step-sqlite-tutorial/). So I guess there is a problem with "cookies.sqlite" file. Any other way around to make it work. Guys please I really need to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I found the solution to the problem of creating "cookies.txt".

**Note**: I don't have corrupt either "cookies.sqlite" nor did my sqlite3 had any problems. I confirmed it by importing in the interpreter of python.

So I have running "cookies.sqlite" and running "sqlite3" but when combined produced "DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database". Follow the steps

- download windows sqlite3 binary from [here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and extract the binary.
- open cmd and run in the extracted directory "sqlite3 cookies.sqlite". you will have sqlite terminal before you. write the following commands in shell.

  .output cookies.txt # this will direct your following commands to file named cookies.txt

  select * from moz_cookies; # this will select all entries from moz_cookies.

There you have your cookies.txt file. [refered link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828440/redirect-the-query-output-to-a-text-file-with-sqlite-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Your code more or less works for me:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sqlite3 import dbapi2
>>> con = dbapi2.connect('cookies.sqlite')
>>> cur = con.cursor()
>>> cur.execute("SELECT name, value, path, host FROM moz_cookies WHERE host LIKE ?", ["%%www.reddit.com%%"])
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10bbb3030>
>>> for item in cur.fetchall():
...     print item[0]
...
loid
loidcreated
loid
loidcreated
```

Maybe the file is corrupt? Can you try opening it with sqlite3 directly?

```
$ sqlite3 cookies.sqlite
SQLite version 3.8.5 2014-08-15 22:37:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT name FROM moz_cookies WHERE host LIKE "%%www.reddit.com%%";
loid
loid
loidcreated
loidcreated
```

Comment: ok...no,no. So I downloaded this zip file named 'sqlite3.zip', or something similar to it. It contained sqlite3.exe. The result I posted in the edit was of that. Otherwise if I run the command on the terminal: "python sqlite3", it says "python: can't open file 'sqlite3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

Comment: So is there a way, I can use this "sqlite3.exe" in the python program. I have read somewhere that, for python 2.5 or up, sqlite3 is already present. Can you suggest me what do I do?